# Create clusters of data points having similar relationships in two columns

Tags: python-3.x, grouping, cluster-analysis, scatter-plot, data-segment

The link given has a dataset with attributes **village_code** and  **delta_progress**. **delta_progress** are nothing but slopes after plotting graphs. I want to create clusters of **village_code** based on these **delta_progress** and **total_progress** columns; by using Python.

[Link to access the data](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1cr4kHz5026F7Z9rUUJbE5xbiabCc9p-l19DU50ThF4E/edit?usp=sharing)

| village_code | delta_progress | total_progress |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 51556 | 3.0569823567654 | 75053.8434034655 |
| 51641 | 0.5296277122346 | 23443.059126711 |

All **village_code** having similar relations in **delta_progress** and **total_progress** should be in the same cluster. I want to plot it like the following Plotly scatter plot or something better if you have...

[image: Plotly Clustering]

[link to the Plotly Clustering](https://plotly.com/python/v3/ipython-notebooks/baltimore-vital-signs/)

Thank you...